# Verifying S3 credentials w/o GET or PUT using boto3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is there a way to verify a given set of S3 credentials has access to a specific bucket without doing an explicit PUT or GET of some sort?

Instantiating an s3.Client, s3.Resource or s3.Bucket object doesn't seem to verify credentials at all, let alone bucket access.

boto3 1.4.7.
python 2.7.13.

We have automation and orchestration that automates bucket creation and I want to include a piece that verifies a user's access key and secret. I know the bucket exists at this point since I created it. The bucket is empty.

I want to verify a user has access w/o doing a PUT operation.

Thanks for any help.

*** update ***

I ended up doing this with an s3.Client object:

```
objects = client.list_objects(Bucket=cfg['bucket'])
```

Since the bucket is empty this is a lightweight operation and a one-liner for the most part. (wrapped in a try block)

Comment: Careful with the `list_objects` method, it will return the first 1000 of them. As an alternative, you can first instantiate the bucket `my_bucket = cfg['bucket']`from the S3 resource  `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')` with `s3_bucket = s3.Bucket(my_bucket)` then you can use the `.objects.all()` method, which will give an `ObjectSummary` iterator, that allows you to get all objects, e.g. `all_objects = [s3.Object(my_bucket, s3_object.key)  for s3_object in s3_bucket.objects.all()]`

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use [IAM policy simulation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.simulate_principal_policy) for that. Here's an example:

```
import boto3

iam = boto3.client('iam')
sts = boto3.client('sts')

# Get the arn represented by the currently configured credentials
arn = sts.get_caller_identity()['Arn']

# Create an arn representing the objects in a bucket
bucket_objects_arn = 'arn:aws:s3:::%s/*' % 'my-test-bucket'

# Run the policy simulation for the basic s3 operations
results = iam.simulate_principal_policy(
    PolicySourceArn=arn,
    ResourceArns=[bucket_objects_arn],
    ActionNames=['s3:PutObject', 's3:GetObject', 's3:DeleteObject']
)
for result in results['EvaluationResults']:
    print("%s - %s" % (result['EvalActionName'], result['EvalDecision']))
```

You can find all the s3 actions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html).

One caveat to this is that IAM is eventually consistent, so if you're creating users on the fly you still might have to wait a bit for the changes to propagate.

Comment: Thank you for posting this example. I have not used the policy simulator in custom code before and this gives me lots of ideas when working with IAM policies.

Comment: Thanks for the info, very useful. I ended up doing something different that seems to be working so far. See my edit above.

Comment: One question... I'm playing with this code and it's complaining about no region. I'm running this in an internal heroku cluster talking to an S3-compat COS.. not actually using AWS. Will this code work i my case?

Comment: @BenH You would just need to specify the region in the environment, code, or your config file. When creating clients, for instance, you can say `boto3.client('us-west-2')`. You can also set `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` or have `region` set in your config file. You'll need to get valid regions from your s3-like service. Also note that the code I posed above will only work for AWS unless you also have IAM and STS compatible services that work with your s3-like service.

Comment: I just set a dummy value and I get past that point but now I get some "UnknownError" issue now. I haven't looked at it much since.

Answer (score 3):

Use [head_bucket](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_bucket).

> head_bucket(**kwargs)
>
> This operation is useful to determine if a
> bucket exists and you have permission to access it.

If you don't have access, you will get an exception:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling
> the HeadBucket operation: Forbidden

Modify this Python 2.7 code to suit to your needs:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
try:
  s3.head_bucket(Bucket='mybucket')
  print 'Can access the bucket'
except:
  print 'Cannot access the bucket'
```

Comment: Note that this only guarantees you have `s3:ListBucket` permissions. You could have read / write access to any subset of objects in a bucket without having that permission granted. You could also only have permission to list without having any editing permissions.