# Verify AWS Credentials with boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to write Python code that uses a number of different AWS keys, some of which may have expired. I need, given an AWS key pair as strings, to check whether the given key pair is valid using boto3. I would prefer not to have to do anything like using os.system to run

```
echo "$aws_key_id
$aws_secret_key\n\n" | aws configure
```

and then reading the response of `aws list-buckets.`

The answer should look something like

```
def check_aws_validity(key_id, secret):
    pass
```

where `key_id` and `secret` are strings.

Note that this is not a repeat of [Verifying S3 credentials w/o GET or PUT using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056628/verifying-s3-credentials-w-o-get-or-put-using-boto3), as I do not have the keys in boto3.profile.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
From John Rotenstein's answer, I got the following function to work.

```
def check_aws_validity(key_id, secret):
    try:
        client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=key_id, aws_secret_access_key=secret)
        response = client.list_buckets()
        return true

    except Exception as e:
        if str(e)!="An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.":
            return true
        return false
```

Comment: What have you written so far?  What's your approach to solving your problem?

Comment: The answer is now in my question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Such a credential-validating method does exist; it's the [STS GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) API call ([boto3 method docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_caller_identity)).

With expired temporary credentials:

```py
>>> import boto3
>>> sts = boto3.client('sts')
>>> sts.get_caller_identity()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jantman/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 276, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/jantman/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is expired
```

With invalid credentials:

```py
>>> import boto3
>>> sts = boto3.client('sts')
>>> sts.get_caller_identity()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jantman/venvs/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/jantman/venvs/current/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 626, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

With valid credentials (IDs replaced with X's):

```py
>>> import boto3
>>> sts = boto3.client('sts')
>>> sts.get_caller_identity()
{'UserId': 'AROAXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXX', 'Account': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'Arn': 'arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/Admin/JANTMAN', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'f44ec1d9-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-a26c85be1c60', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'f44ec1d9-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-a26c85be1c60', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '426', 'date': 'Thu, 28 May 2020 10:45:36 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Invalid credentials will raise an exception and valid credentials won't, so you can do something such as:

```py
import boto3
sts = boto3.client('sts')
try:
    sts.get_caller_identity()
    print("Credentials are valid.")
except boto3.exceptions.ClientError:
    print("Credentials are NOT valid.")
```

Comment: The exception here should be `botocore.exceptions.ClientError`, but it's also possible to get a `botocore.exceptions.CredentialRetrievalError` if (for example) access to macOS Keychain credentials is denied. This will be triggered by the `client()` call.

Comment: @rcoup it will actually throw another error when trying to catch the "boto3.exceptions.ClientError" for me - I don't know if that's just because my computer is better than yours or not (lol). So I have to use "botocore" instead of "boto3". So far I've only received "ClientError" and haven't stumbled into "CredentialRetrievalError". For everyone else's sake (as well as mine): How is that triggered? Should I catch it? Is there a way to catch both with the same except clause? Thank you kindly, stranger.

Answer (score 7):

You can make a call by directly specifying credentials:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='xxx', aws_secret_access_key='xxx')
response = client.list_buckets()
```

You can then use the response to determine whether the credentials are valid.

However, it is possible that a user has valid credentials, but does not have permission to call `list_buckets()`. This might make it harder to determine whether they have valid credentials. You'll need to try various combinations to see what response is sent back to your code.

Comment: I know that on the command line if the keys are invalid, the user will get an InvalidAccessKeyId error. Is there any related exception in boto3?

Comment: Yes. Try the code with various combinations of valid credentials, invalid credentials and "valid credentials without permission to call list-buckets()" to see the errors returned.

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a generic `client.validate_credentials()` function.

Comment: @keithpjolley not necessarily. it may be a good to have feature, but it may lead to security risks. If a such a method would exist, it **may** lead to better recon for an adversary, should the adversary find a pair of creds.

Comment: or, if you lose your keys you change your locks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved that:

```
import boto3
import botocore

def check_login():
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    try:
        sts.get_caller_identity()
        return True
    except botocore.exceptions.UnauthorizedSSOTokenError:
        return False

if check_login():
    print("Credentials are valid.")
else:
    # do something to log in
```

The difference to the answer before is the import of botocore and the catch of the correct error (UnauthorizedSSOTokenError).
Also it works with Python3 (e. g. new boolean types to return).