# checking if aws credentials are configured in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a python script that uses boto3 to send data to s3. Is there anyway I can check to see if aws credentials are configured on the host machine? If it is not, I want to be able to output a certain functionality.

Let me know

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62062926/6673446 . It seems to answer this question directly.

Comment: just try to list bucket using your access key if you get the response your keys are correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/53548875/13126651